# Add elements from vector to every nth column of dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have the following vector:

```
samples <- c("bl", "ra", "ye", "gp", "dk")
```

which I would like to add to the dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(Country = "FR", Name = "Jean", A="",B="",C="",D="",E="",F="",G="",H="",I="",J="",K="",L="",M="",N="",O="",P="",Q="",R="",S="",T="",U="",V="",W="ok",X="ok",Y="ok",Z="ok",A1="ok",B1="ok")
```

and give the output

```
  Country Name   A  B   C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T ....
1      FR Jean   bl           ra          ye          gp          dk
```

The aim:

- Place elements within the vector into the dataframe that already contains some values.
- The first element has to be in column 3
- Subsequent elements have to be in every 5th column from the first element i.e columns 7, 11, 15, 19, ... (4i-1)
- A for loop that automatically adds the elements every 5th column from the first element. Depending on the situation, I may have a much longer vector than what I specified. It would be tedious to assign each element to the column names individually.

Comment: In your example data column `K` is lost. I have added it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of a loop. You can directly assign `samples` to the corresponding columns.

```r
df[, seq_along(samples) * 4 - 1] <- samples

df
#   Country Name  A B C D  E F G H  I J K L  M N O P  Q R S T U V  W  X  Y  Z A1 B1
# 1      FR Jean bl       ra       ye       gp       dk           ok ok ok ok ok ok
```

Comment: Hi Darren, appreciate your help. I've edited the question because of a typo on my part. I would like the first element to be in column "A" instead. What changes will I need?
I've tried: 
for (i in 1:length(samples)) df[, seq_along(samples) * 4-1] <- samples,
and seems to work too.

Comment: @Loki123 see my update! I have said that there is no need to use a loop.

Answer (score 1):

First define a `target_pos` vector containing the position of your target columns, then iterate over the vector to append `samples` to your `df`.

Note there's some differences between your input `df` and your desired output. For example you don't have column `K` in your df but you have that in your desired output.

```r
target_pos <- seq(3, 5*length(samples) - 3, 4)

for (i in 1:length(target_pos)) df[, target_pos[i]] <- samples[i]

df
#>   Country Name  A B C D  E F G H  I J L M  N O P Q  R S T U V  W  X  Y  Z A1 B1
#> 1      FR Jean bl       ra       ye       gp       dk         ok ok ok ok ok ok
```

#### Data

```
df<-data.frame(Country = "FR", Name = "Jean", A="",B="",C="",D="",E="",F="",G="",H="",I="",J="",L="",M="",N="",O="",P="",Q="",R="",S="",T="",U="",V="",W="ok",X="ok",Y="ok",Z="ok",A1="ok",B1="ok")

samples=c("bl","ra","ye","gp","dk")
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. Seems to work, however it will replace some values with NA. Any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: @Loki123 Updated code to fit your request, there will not be `NA` now and the column index started at A